# Android build problem when I clear app data?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, build

I made a mini mobile game on Unity3d. It has many scenes (each level in the game is a scene). the levels start from scene number 1 but there is a scene number 0 which contains an empty that has a script attached to it "Level0".

```
 public class Level0 : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public int levelIndex;
     public IEnumerator delayCoroutine()
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
         SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelIndex);
     }
     void Awake()
     {
         levelIndex = SaveLoadManager.loadCurrentLevelIndex();
         StartCoroutine(delayCoroutine());
     }
 }
```

the role of this script is to call a static function from "SaveLoadManager" which returns the next level index (scene index in the build settings).

```
 public static int loadCurrentLevelIndex()
     {
         if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.txt"))
         {
             BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
             FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.txt", FileMode.Open);
             PlayerDataSerializable data = bf.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerDataSerializable;
             stream.Close();
             return data.realCurrentLevel;
         }
         else
         {
             return 1;
         }
     }
```

so the method gets the level index from the data file but if the file is not found it just returns "1".

Now the problem is that when I build the game to my OPPO A73 with Android 10 and enter the app settings and choose"clear data" and reopen the game, then it crashes at level0. however when I do the same thing with Nokia 3 (Android 9) or Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 (Android 11) the game works fine and loads the first level as expected.

I monitored the errors via Logcat in Android Studio but I didn't get any error from Unity.

Is the problem with my OPPO device? because I got this error in Logcat:

> E/DispScene: [/data/oppo/multimedia/oppo_display_perf_list.xml]:open
> config fail

Or with Android 10?

Comment: I usually filter logs looking for the word "exception", and then I can start investigating with the stack trace.